# Cannot get variable to pass to array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, statistics

I'm trying to recreate a PHP script I made in JS, but I'm getting stuck here:

```
var array1 = [];
var array2 = [];

for (x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    do {
        var rand1 = Math.random();
        var rand2 = Math.random();
        var x1 = 2.0 * rand1 - 1.0;
        var x2 = 2.0 * rand2 - 1.0;
        var w = Math.pow(x1, 2) + Math.pow(x2, 2);
    } while (w === 0 || w > 1);
    multiplier = Math.sqrt((-2 * Math.log(w)) / w);
    var y1 = x1 * multiplier;
    var y2 = x2 * multiplier;
    array1.push(y1);
    array2.push(y2);
}
for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    document.write(array1[i] . "<br />");
}
```

For some reason, I cannot print the array, and the script just stops working when I try to push y1 and y2 into arrays. What is causing this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/92wj8cv9/ see the console, I have the same code as yours, but you have just made a syntaxt error,  `document.write(array1[i] . "<br />");`

Try changing it to `document.write(array1[i] + "<br />");`

Comment: Whoops. Guess a little PHP snuck in. Thanks!